# Parsing a tag with JSOUP force closing for nullPointerException

Tags: android, jsoup

When trying to parse the link

http://pc.gamespy.com/pc/bastion/

using

```
Element overview = doc.select("div#object-overview").last();
    Element paragraph = overview.select("p").last();
```

It gives me a nullpointerexception.

And also with this one

http://wii.gamespy.com/wii/jerry-rice-nitus-dog-football/

it gives null pointer here

```
Element featureList = doc.select("div.callout-box").last();
featuresText.setText("FEATURE: " + featureList.text());
```

Why is this? I am trying to retrieve the overview section. it works for all the other items.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://jsoup.org/apidocs/, Jsoup throws `NullPointerException` if the argument is null. In other words rather `.select("div#object-overview")` returns null or `.select("p")`. Try to check for null first, then use `.last()` method like this

```
Elements overviews = doc.select("div#object-overview");
if(!overview==null){
Element overview = overviews.last();
}
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

On the first one you should be able to simply call

```
Element overview = doc.select("#object-overview").last();
```

You shouldn't need the div as part of it since `object-overview` is an `id`.  You were getting the NullPointerException because the expression in your select was incorrect, so `select` returned null because it couldn't find anything.

Not sure why the second one wouldn't work for you.  I can see there is at least one div with the class callout-box.  Unless `featuresText` is null?