# Android - Jsoup - SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, jsoup, socket-timeout-exception

I'm trying to develop an Android app which uses jsoup-1.7.1.jar core library. I included the jar-file as a library but now when I want to use it, I'll receive a SocketTimeoutException everytime.
I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04, eclipse-juno Build id: 20120614-1722, emulator/avd has 100MB of sd, 512Ram and is on API-Level 16.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenue, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    //Yes I'm aware that this should not be done. I'm planing to use it in the AsyncTask
    //doInBackground method, but since it was not working there, I decided to track it
    //down here in the main-activity -> so it's just for debug
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    Document doc = null;
    String url1 = "http://213.165.64.71";
    String url2 = "http://www.google.com";
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url2).timeout(10*1000).get();
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException a) {
        Log.e("MyAPP", "Exception----------A!", a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyAPP", "Exception----------E!", e);
    }
    String title = doc.title();
    Log.i("MyAPP", "Title="+title);
}
}
```

Error-Log:

```
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433): Exception----------A!
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:491)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream.readChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:77)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:47)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:304)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.readToByteBuffer(DataUtil.java:113)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:447)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:429)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:393)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:159)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:148)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at de.funkypopcorn.reggae_a_gwaan.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-05 10:45:23.680: E/MyAPP(1433):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     ... 11 more
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     at de.funkypopcorn.reggae_a_gwaan.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
10-05 10:45:23.730: E/AndroidRuntime(1433):     ... 14 more
```

Yes, I've searched all different kind of postings and didn't find any solution for my problem.
(including this one: [How to use AsyncTask for Jsoup Parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083680/how-to-use-asynctask-for-jsoup-parser))

- Yes I have Internet permission in my Manifest.xml (WebView works great)
- I changed the proxy settings to no-proxy (even though I don't believe it's caused by that, because before the WebView was working as well).
- I tried with different pages and even with plain Ip (so no prob of the DNS)

Maybe there is something obvious misssing? Help really appreciated, thx in advance!

Edit1: According to wireshark the request is send and the answer is given back:
[image: wireshark-cap]

Edit2: It is really strange, sometimes it works and I get an answer. But 3min later when I try it again it does not work anymore. The problem is that it only works ~ 1 out of 10 times. Any ideas?

Comment: not so far, sorry! The project is on ice for about 3 months already. I'll let you know when I continue in March or April.

Comment: I have a similar problem and resolved with this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10248321/2087208